# How to create a CheckListBox in wx python that allows multiple selections - wxComboBox

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to create a collapsible checkbox using wx python 2.9.5.0 with Python 2.7 that allows multiple options to be checked.

[The following qustion seems to get close,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906110/is-it-possible-to-make-an-accordion-style-check-list-in-wxpython) but it's missing a few major things. It references the "[ComboCtrl example in the demo](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/ComboCtrl.html#comboctrl)". However, when I tried to run that sample, I got an error that wx doesn't have an attribute ComboCtrl. That was fixed by calling wx.combo.ComboCtrl. However, I can't seem to find ListViewComboPopup() in any combination of wx or wx.combo.

Where does that ListViewComboPopup() function live?

For Reference, here is my current attempt at the code:

```
class MyFrame ( wx.Frame ):
    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        bSIZER = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        comboCtrl = combo.ComboCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        popupCtrl = wx.combo.ListViewComboPopup()

        # It is important to call SetPopupControl() as soon as possible
        comboCtrl.SetPopupControl(popupCtrl)
        # Populate using wx.ListView methods
        popupCtrl.InsertItem(popupCtrl.GetItemCount(), "First Item")
        popupCtrl.InsertItem(popupCtrl.GetItemCount(), "Second Item")
        popupCtrl.InsertItem(popupCtrl.GetItemCount(), "Third Item")

        bSIZER.Add( comboCtrl, 1, wx.ALL, 

        self.SetSizer( bSIZER )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass
```

Running that gives the following error:
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ListViewComboPopup'

Once I get this working, I'm still a few steps from creating the drop down menu with multiple options, but I this is the big current stumbling block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://zetcode.com/wxpython/advanced/ and check out the section on

> CheckListCtrl
>   The code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# repository.py

import wx
import sys
from wx.lib.mixins.listctrl import CheckListCtrlMixin, ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin

packages = [('abiword', '5.8M', 'base'), ('adie', '145k', 'base'),
    ('airsnort', '71k', 'base'), ('ara', '717k', 'base'), ('arc', '139k', 'base'),
    ('asc', '5.8M', 'base'), ('ascii', '74k', 'base'), ('ash', '74k', 'base')]

class CheckListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl, CheckListCtrlMixin, ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT | wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        CheckListCtrlMixin.__init__(self)
        ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin.__init__(self)


class Repository(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(450, 400))

        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        leftPanel = wx.Panel(panel, -1)
        rightPanel = wx.Panel(panel, -1)

        self.log = wx.TextCtrl(rightPanel, -1, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.list = CheckListCtrl(rightPanel)
        self.list.InsertColumn(0, 'Package', width=140)
        self.list.InsertColumn(1, 'Size')
        self.list.InsertColumn(2, 'Repository')

        for i in packages:
            index = self.list.InsertStringItem(sys.maxint, i[0])
            self.list.SetStringItem(index, 1, i[1])
            self.list.SetStringItem(index, 2, i[2])

        vbox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        sel = wx.Button(leftPanel, -1, 'Select All', size=(100, -1))
        des = wx.Button(leftPanel, -1, 'Deselect All', size=(100, -1))
        apply = wx.Button(leftPanel, -1, 'Apply', size=(100, -1))


        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnSelectAll, id=sel.GetId())
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnDeselectAll, id=des.GetId())
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnApply, id=apply.GetId())

        vbox2.Add(sel, 0, wx.TOP, 5)
        vbox2.Add(des)
        vbox2.Add(apply)

        leftPanel.SetSizer(vbox2)

        vbox.Add(self.list, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.TOP, 3)
        vbox.Add((-1, 10))
        vbox.Add(self.log, 0.5, wx.EXPAND)
        vbox.Add((-1, 10))

        rightPanel.SetSizer(vbox)

        hbox.Add(leftPanel, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.RIGHT, 5)
        hbox.Add(rightPanel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        hbox.Add((3, -1))

        panel.SetSizer(hbox)

        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

    def OnSelectAll(self, event):
        num = self.list.GetItemCount()
        for i in range(num):
            self.list.CheckItem(i)

    def OnDeselectAll(self, event):
        num = self.list.GetItemCount()
        for i in range(num):
            self.list.CheckItem(i, False)

    def OnApply(self, event):
        num = self.list.GetItemCount()
        for i in range(num):
            if i == 0: self.log.Clear()
            if self.list.IsChecked(i):
                self.log.AppendText(self.list.GetItemText(i) + '\n')

app = wx.App()
Repository(None, -1, 'Repository')
app.MainLoop()
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For python version 3 and above, the code can be simplified:

- mixins can be removed (cancel CheckListCtrl class)
- use control wx.ListCtrl:

  ```
    self.list = wx.ListCtrl(rightPanel)
    self.list.EnableCheckBoxes()
  ```